# Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 dual boot on ssd + hdd raid1

Tags: boot, windows, raid, ssd

Despite reading dozens of HowTos and so on I am getting crazy about trying to get my dual boot system running. Maybe you can help me.

My system:

- Asus Z87-pro motherboard with UEFI
- Samsung 840 Pro 256 GB SSD
- 2 x Seagate Desktop (former Barracuda) 1 TB HDD
- 16 GB RAM

What I want to do:

- Install Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit and Ubuntu 12.04 parallel on SSD:

  200 GB of SSD NFTS partition for Windows
  50 GB of SSD EXT2 for Ubuntu, / folder
  16 GB of SSD as SWAP for Ubuntu
- Have the HDDs in RAID 1 ('FakeRaid' by Motherboard controller) as data disk in NFTS
- Alternative: Ubuntu on the RAID disk

What I tried:

- Windows on SSD / Ubuntu on HDD Raid

  - Create RAID 1 with Raid Controller during PC start
  - Windows installation on SSD
  - Linux installation on RAID

  **Problem**: Grub does not recognize Windows
- Windows and Ubuntu on SSD A

  - Create RAID 1 with Raid Controller during PC start
  - Windows installation on SSD
  - Linux installation on SSD

  **Problem**: Ubuntu does not recognize Windows installation and wants to overwrite the whole SSD
- Windows and Ubuntu on SSD B

  - Disconnect HDDs from mainboard
  - Windows installation on SSD
  - Linux installation on SSD

  **Problem**: Ubuntu does not recognize Windows installation and wants to overwrite the whole SSD
- I also have tried to pre-partitionate the disks with GParted, did not work neither.

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Some of my questions:

- Why does Ubuntu not recognize Windows?
- Can I install Ubuntu on a RAIDed disk?
- Where to install the bootmanager?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to completely forgo RAID and to do this:

1) Use Windows Disk Defragment to clean up the drive

2) Use GParted to shrink the Windows partition to 200GB

(From now on, follow only #a, or only #b instructions, but not both)

3a) In the Ubuntu installer select 'Install alongside Windows 7' if it's available

3b) If it's not available, select 'Something Else'

4a) Let the installer do it's work and continue with life as normal

4b) Create a 16GB partition to use as swap

5b) Create apartition using the rest of the space on the SSD to serve as the main Ubuntu partition

6b) Select to use the partitions as swap (for the 16GB) and / (for the main partition) and to format them.

7b) Let it install

8b) Boot Ubuntu with your BIOS boot manager (usually press F8 or ESC or something during bootup, it will tell you)

9b) Run this in Terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

10b) You should see a list of various kernels, including Windows 7.

11b) Reboot and enjoy

FINAL STEP: Format the 1TB drive as NTFS inside Windows 7, and it will be shared between the two OS's.

*No matter what, don't format your Windows partition, or you will lose it.  It is always wise to backup data before any project, to prevent data loss.